# Get video's duration

Tags: c++

I have tried, in vain, to fetch the duration of a video file using c++. I'm on a Linux platform. How do I go about it?
Is there some file on my native file system where this information is stored, or does it move with the video file?
Google gives me every method on ruby, c# etc etc, but I haven't found any libraries for c++.

Comment: What type of video file is it?

Comment: it is mostly avi, but I definitely need support with other formats like flv, mkv, wmv, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Give [libavcodec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec) a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look at **midentify** source code. It's a tool that come with mplayer (http://www.mplayerhq.hu/). If you're too lazy, you can take it's output and parse it in your c++ application